# нужно на модальное окно добавить анимацию без использования css! только через js

Tags: javascript, анимация, modal

```
const modal = () => {
    const modal = document.querySelector('.popup');
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.popup-btn');
    const closeBtn = modal.querySelector('.popup-close');

    buttons.forEach(btn => {
        btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            modal.style.display = 'block';
            
        });
    });
    closeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        modal.style.display = 'none';
    });
    window.onclick = (e) => {
        if (e.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    };
};

export default modal;
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Пожалуйста поделитесь своим минимальным воспроизводимым кодом!